# Entity Framework Core cascade delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-relationship

I have two classes:

```
public class Player
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public Username { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}

public class Device
{
     public int DeviceId { get; set; }
     public string DeviceInfo { get; set; }

     public int PlayerId { get; set; }
     public virtual Player { get; set; }
}
```

How should I configure fluent api if I need to establish relationship one to many (many devices for one player) with a behavior where I want to delete all Device records belonging to Player I want to delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the delete action in Entity Framework by default is Cascade Delete

so you follow the convention and you don't have to add any code